# wampserver orange icon after running script php

Tags: php, localhost, simple-html-dom

in running script php in localhost my wampserver gives orang icon

i used simple_html_dom ??

```
[Sun Aug 10 02:00:46 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_phar.dll' - Le module sp\xe9cifi\xe9 est introuvable.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_phar.dll' - Le module spécifié est introuvable.
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Sun Aug 10 02:00:47 2014] [notice] Child 7708: Child process is running
[Sun Aug 10 02:00:47 2014] [notice] Child 7708: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Aug 10 02:00:47 2014] [notice] Child 7708: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Aug 10 02:00:47 2014] [notice] Child 7708: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Aug 10 02:00:47 2014] [notice] Child 7708: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
EACCELERATOR: Open for write failed for "/tmp/eaccelerator/5/d//eaccelerator-5d1d91f1f159bd69483f3d3a30e73748": No such file or directory
EACCELERATOR cached: "C:\wamp\www\simplehtmldom_1_5\test\prod.php"
EACCELERATOR: Open for write failed for "/tmp/eaccelerator/4/1//eaccelerator-41e2af476b0cde3b704cecd182b293f6": No such file or directory
EACCELERATOR cached: "C:\wamp\www\simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom.php"
[Sun Aug 10 02:00:47 2014
] [notice] EACCELERATOR(7708): PHP crashed on opline 15 of clear() at C:\wamp\www\simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom.php:1119

[Sun Aug 10 02:00:53 2014] [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting
```

.

Comment: Seems pretty straightfoward? `Unable to load dynamic library '...php_phar.dll'` You haven't got phar installed properly.

Comment: I installed php extension